# update text in select using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to update an option text and I do not have #id of the select box.

I found examples like this:

```
$('#selectid option:contains("OLD_TEXT_VALUE")').text('newtext');
```

I can't use this example, since I can only access select like this:

```
selectedField.find('select')
```

how do I add

```
option:contains("OLD_TEXT_VALUE")').text('newtext');
```

to the above way of selecting select, is it possible?

This is my code, there can be many selects dynamically inserted into the page in this format.

```
<div id="basic_select_xxxx" class="form-group selectable">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option>Select something</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I can select the select only like this:

$('#basic_select_xxxx').find('select).

how to then update select option with new text by looking up the old value? Is it possible this way? I can not put id on select, so let me know if there is other way?

Comment: post your html. Is there only `one select` in the whole page?

Comment: what's the value of `selectedField`

Comment: there can be many selects and I do not know their ids. I will update my question to give you a bit more detail

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `chain your jQuery` Do something like:

```
$('#basic_select_xxxx').find('select option:contains("OLD_TEXT_VALUE")').text('newtext');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the containers ID's start with same `"basic_select_"` prefix you can use that in an ["attribute starts with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('.selectable[id^="basic_select_"] select option:contains("OLD_TEXT_VALUE")').text('newtext');
```